# Enable serving of files with no extension in PHP 7.4 on Azure

Tags: php, azure, web-config, static-files

I am running Wordpress on Azure under PHP 7.4 and require the ability to serve files with no file extensions on my PHP site.

The url I am trying to load looks like this `https://myurl.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/6uVkXzXxHHkm1d6cQiUqI07lrYspInk7i9WCKKl-RlQ`

Unfortunately no matter what I seem to do I am still getting a `404 Page Not Found` error on WordPress despite the file existing on my server.

Typically in .NET applications all I need to do is add a configuration setting to the web.config like such to achieve the desired result.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/html" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also tried adding a custom .htaccess file with the following values.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\. - [H=text/html]
```

but unfortunately the error persists.

Can anyone provide any guidance on how I might be able to get this working?

Comment: Is this a managed service on Azure or are you using some type of web server on a VM?  There usually isn't any specific configuration required for this type of functionality, just putting .well-known in your web root should be sufficient.

Comment: @Devon This is running as a managed App Service on a Windows App Service Plan

Comment: Thank you @Devon for your confirmation that this should simply work. It was enough for me to put the pieces together and work out what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the mistake I was making was trying to place the file in a subfolder called wwwroot inside of wwwroot like you do with a .NET application.

This was a mistake on my part having come from .NET.

Upon moving the file to the actual wwwroot folder I was able to successfully resolve my issue.